# RSpec Stops Running After ActiveRecord Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

Quick question:

My RSpec snippet:

```
  it 'is invalid with a duplicate email address' do
    jakeSnow = Contact.new(
      firstname: 'Jake',
      lastname: 'Snow',
      email: 'lordcommander@nightswatch.com'
    )
    expect(jakeSnow).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
  end
```

There is a jonSnow persisted to the database with the above email already taken. When I run rspec in the terminal, I get an ActiveRecord error:

```
 Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

And the tests seem to stop running. My goal is to test that using a taken email will return an error. After my test validates this, I want to proceed along and not stop because it encounters an error. How should I rewrite the code to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have `config.fail_fast = true` in your spec_helper? Or `--fail-fast` in `.rspec` file in your app root?

Comment: Further questions - is your test database clean? Do you use FactoryGirl with lint? The error you showed has no right to be thrown by the example you gave - you are not running validations here at all.

Comment: thought the same as BroiSatse actually creation of a new model does not automaticly trigger validation and thus adding errors to the model, can you try somthing like expect{jackSnow.valid?}.to change{jackSnow.errors}.from(nil).to(...) and btw it is jonSnow...

Comment: Well, Jack is stealing Jon's email, hence the need to check and deny this ^.^

I tried config.fail_fast = true and --fail-fast in .rspec as well, still get the error (remember I have a jonSnow persisted with the above email, and there's a validates uniqueness for email).

Comment: Are you sure the error is from this example, and not another one?

Comment: I think I got it, it wasn't an issue with jonSnow/jakeSnow, but rather that rerunning the spec keep saving jonSnow to the test DB, while he was already persisted after the first run. Adding the database cleaner gem solved this problem. Thanks guys!